# Selecting an oracle xmltype table field into an xmltype variable results in a null object

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

This has been bugging me for a while. I'm using oracle streams to write messages to an oracle AQ queue as part of a stored procedure. Below is the stored proc with relevent sections shown:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ESBEVENT.esb_dml_handler(in_any IN ANYDATA) IS

l_enqueue_options dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
l_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
l_message sys.aq$_jms_text_message;
l_msgid raw(16);
l_xmlmsg SYS.XMLTYPE;
err_num NUMBER;
err_msg VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
    BEGIN
    l_message := sys.aq$_jms_text_message.construct;
    l_xmlmsg := DBMS_STREAMS.CONVERT_LCR_TO_XML(in_any);
    l_message.set_text(l_xmlmsg.getClobVal());

    dbms_aq.enqueue
    ( queue_name => 'esbevent.esb_jms_queue'
    , enqueue_options => l_enqueue_options
    , message_properties => l_message_properties
    , payload => l_message
    , msgid => l_msgid
    );
    COMMIT;

    err_num := '';
    err_msg := 'Message Queued Successfully';

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        err_num := SQLCODE;
        err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
        INSERT INTO esbevent.esb_dml_handler_error_t VALUES (SYSDATE, err_num||' - '||err_msg );
END;

INSERT INTO esbevent.esb_jms_msg_memento_t VALUES (esb_jms_msg_memento_seq.nextval,     SYSDATE, l_xmlmsg, err_num||' - '||err_msg );
COMMIT;


END;
```

Following the enqueue I store the message that was sent as an XMLTYPE in the table esb_jms_msg_memento_t. This is to enable resends if we have issues in subsequent processing. I'm now trying to write a block that will extract the XMLTYPE field data and write it again to the AQ. This is currently as follows:

```
DECLARE
   l_enqueue_options      DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   l_message_properties   DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   l_message              SYS.aq$_jms_text_message;
   l_msgid                RAW (16);
   l_xmlmsg               XMLTYPE;

BEGIN
   SELECT msg_payload
     INTO l_xmlmsg
     FROM esb_jms_msg_memento_t
    WHERE UNIQUE_ID = '815929';

   l_message.set_text (l_xmlmsg.getClobVal ()); --null self error here


   DBMS_AQ.enqueue (queue_name           => 'esbevent.esb_jms_queue',
                    enqueue_options      => l_enqueue_options,
                    message_properties   => l_message_properties,
                    payload              => l_message,
                    msgid                => l_msgid);
   COMMIT;
END;
```

When i run this I get the error:

ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: at line 22

It appears I can insert and XMLTYPE variable to an XMLTYPE field but not the other way around???

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I post I solve it...

forgot to construct the l_message:

```
l_message := sys.aq$_jms_text_message.construct;
```

doh!

Comment: am Iallowed to up tick myself for this or down tick for wasting so much of my own time

Comment: Writing down the problem makes you think about it more clearly and makes if possible that you solve it yourself. Hardly a waste of time. And I guess we all here at Stackoverflow can say: glad to be of help.